# Arabic single characters remain after removing stop words in python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I have a list called strings which it's content is lists of Arabic words and these are the first two rows for example:

1st list:['اطلاله', 'انيقه', 'وانثويه', 'من', 'مجموعه', 'غوتشي', 'لخريفشتاء'],

2nd list:['اخر', 'صيحه', 'من', 'حقاءب', 'اليد', 'من', 'فندي', 'وغوتشي', 'غوتشي', 'بناتالخبر']

I want to remove stop words but the result is lists of only Arabic characters like these:

1st list after removing stop words: {'ا', 'ن', 'ر', 'ع', 'ت', 'غ', ' ', 'ج', 'ق', 'و', 'ط', 'ي', 'ف', 'ه', 'م', 'ل', 'ش', 'خ', 'ء', 'ث'}

2st list after removing stop words: {'ا', 'ن', 'ر', 'ت', 'غ', ' ', 'ق', 'و', 'ي', 'د', 'ف', 'ه', 'م', 'ح', 'ل', 'ش', 'خ', 'ء', 'ص', 'ب'}

The same goes for the rest of the lists. and here is my code:

```
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('arabic')
keywords=[]
for i in range(len(strings)):
   keywords.append({w for w in strings[i] if not w in stopwords_list})
for k in range(len(keywords)):
    print(k,keywords[k])
```

so what is the problem? please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Arabic-Stopwords python library for remove Arabic stop words

> pip install Arabic-Stopwords

```
import arabicstopwords.arabicstopwords as stp

list_one = ['اطلاله', 'انيقه', 'وانثويه', 'من', 'مجموعه', 'غوتشي', 'لخريفشتاء']
keywords = []

for word in list_one:
    if not stp.is_stop(word):
        keywords.append(word)
    else:
        pass
for word in keywords:
    print(word)
```